# tomcat application started but destroy immediately

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I have deployed my application in my linux box. I am using easy `apache tomcat 7` version. I am able to see my tomcat `context is initialized` **but immediately after initialization**, context is getting destroyed. I am not seeing any exception happening in the log file.

> [Loaded
>   org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap$EntryIterator from
>   file:/var/cache/easy-tomcat7/work/Catalina/web.com/web-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar]
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Published root
>   WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name
>   [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT] INFO :
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root
>   WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7637 ms INFO :
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext -
>   Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun May 22 07:58:10
>   UTC 2016]; root of context hierarchy   DEBUG:
>   org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver -
>   Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in
>   [servletConfigInitParams] DEBUG:
>   org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver -
>   Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in
>   [servletContextInitParams] DEBUG:
>   org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found
>   key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [servletContextInitParams]
>   with type [String] and value 'dev' DEBUG:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -
>   Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
>   DEBUG:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -
>   Destroying singletons in
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2b48a930:

This is the web.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>web</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/log4j.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>  
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>  
    <param-value>dev</param-value>  
</context-param>  
<context-param>  
    <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>  
    <param-value>dev</param-value>  
</context-param>
<context-param>  
    <param-name>spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain</param-name>  
    <param-value>dev</param-value>  
</context-param>  
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/login/auth</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml            
            /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-context.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>web</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>web</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

root-context.xml

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd">        


</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have profile specific configuration defined in your @Configuration classes, such as

```
 @Configuration
 public class MyConfig {

   @Configuration
   @Profile(value="dev")
   public static class DevConfiuration {
        @Bean
        ///some bean methods here
   }
 }
```

if not, try removing below profiles tags altogether and see if it gets deployed.

```
  <context-param>  
     <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>  
     <param-value>dev</param-value>  
 </context-param>  
 <context-param>  
     <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>  
     <param-value>dev</param-value>  
 </context-param>
 <context-param>  
     <param-name>spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain</param-name>  
     <param-value>dev</param-value>  
 </context-param>
```